# Make combination inside list of tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I was working on some other question . I have below list

```
[(['1', '2', '3'], 'abc'), (['4', '5', '6'], 'xyz')]
```

Output should be below

```
[('1', 'abc'), ('2', 'abc'), ('3', 'abc'), ('4', 'xyz'), ('5', 'xyz'), ('6', 'xyz')]
```

My attempt is
First i unlist the list inside it

```
l1=[ tuple(i[0])+(i[1],) for i in l ]
print (l1)
[('1', '2', '3', 'abc'), ('4', '5', '6', 'xyz')]
```

Then tried product from itertools , but it is not giving me the required result. Problem is 'abc' is getting splited in 'a','b','c' using product.

```
from itertools import product
[ list(product(i[:-1],i[-1])) for i in l1 ]

[[('1', 'a'),
  ('1', 'b'),
  ('1', 'c'),
  ('2', 'a'),
  ('2', 'b'),
  ('2', 'c'),
  ('3', 'a'),
  ('3', 'b'),
  ('3', 'c')],
 [('4', 'x'),
  ('4', 'y'),
  ('4', 'z'),
  ('5', 'x'),
  ('5', 'y'),
  ('5', 'z'),
  ('6', 'x'),
  ('6', 'y'),
  ('6', 'z')]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) as long as you wrap the string in an iterable so that it is handled as a single element of an iterable rather than iterated.

```
from itertools import product

data = [(['1', '2', '3'], 'abc'), (['4', '5', '6'], 'xyz')]

combos = [combo for a, b in data for combo in product(a, [b])]
print(combos)
# [('1', 'abc'), ('2', 'abc'), ('3', 'abc'), ('4', 'xyz'), ('5', 'xyz'), ('6', 'xyz')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension:

```
L=[(['1', '2', '3'], 'abc'), (['4', '5', '6'], 'xyz')]                                                                

In: [ (n,s) for l,s in L for n in l ]                                                                                     
Out: 
[('1', 'abc'),
 ('2', 'abc'),
 ('3', 'abc'),
 ('4', 'xyz'),
 ('5', 'xyz'),
 ('6', 'xyz')]
```

As you can write:

```
rslt=[]
for l,s in L:
   for n in l:
     rslt.append((n,s))
```

Answer (score 2):

product from itertools is working as intended. The issue is that Python strings are *iterable*, so product is iterating through the elements of the string. If you want to treat the string as a single element, you can put it into a list and feed the list to product

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
ls = [(['1', '2', '3'], 'abc'), (['4', '5', '6'], 'xyz')]
ls_new = [(a,b) for n,b in ls for a in n]
print(ls_new)
```